# How would I make this box style show straight above the div block rather than off to the right?

Tags: css

[box-shadow-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2AgC.png)

Here is the code and the website where I found the style. Thank you.

https://getcssscan.com/css-box-shadow-examples

```css
box-shadow: blue 0px 0px 0px 2px inset, rgb(255, 255, 255) 10px -10px 0px -3px, rgb(31, 193, 27) 10px -10px, rgb(255, 255, 255) 20px -20px 0px -3px, rgb(255, 217, 19) 20px -20px, rgb(255, 255, 255) 30px -30px 0px -3px, rgb(255, 156, 85) 30px -30px, rgb(255, 255, 255) 40px -40px 0px -3px, rgb(255, 85, 85) 40px -40px;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
border-radius: 60px
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the X and Y values. (first 2 values after the color)

```css
div {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: blue 0px 0px 0px 3px inset, 
  rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px -10px 0px -3px, 
  rgb(31, 193, 27) 0px -10px, 
  rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px -20px 0px -3px, 
  rgb(255, 217, 19) 0px -20px, 
  rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px -30px 0px -3px, 
  rgb(255, 156, 85) 0px -30px, 
  rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px -40px 0px -3px, 
  rgb(255, 85, 85) 0px -40px; 
  padding-top: 50px; 
  padding-bottom: 50px; 
  border-radius: 60px: white;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Yo! Thanks for answering. I've been changing the x and y values but can't seem to get it vertical to the top. It's either they stack left or stack right. Any ideas on how to get it to stack at the top only? Appreciate it.

Comment: @callumnoble Edited my snippet. Run it again. Is this what you mean?

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: @callumnoble np, take care

Answer (score 0):

center origin and `spread-radius` of shadow:

```css
.box {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: blue 0px 0px 0px 2px inset, rgb(255 255 255) 0 0 0px 4px, rgb(31 193 27) 0 0px 0 6px, rgb(255 255 255) 0 0 0px 8px, rgb(255 217 19) 0 0 0px 10px, rgb(255 255 255) 0 0 0px 12px, rgb(255 156 85) 0 0 0 14px, rgb(255 255 255) 0 0 0px 16px, rgb(255 85 85) 0 0 0 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Yo! Thanks for the response. This code covers the whole div, do you know to just have it aligned to the top instead of slanted to the right in my first example? I appreciate your time, thanks.